# MVVMCross Android button enable

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to MVVMCross framework for Android and having trouble on how to enable/disable a button. I wasn't able to find a documentation around this area. 


Code ViewModel:

```
    private bool _buttonEnabled;
    public bool ButtonEnabled
    {
        get
        { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailLogin);}
        set
        {
            _buttonEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ButtonEnabled);
        }
    }
```

**Android axml:**

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Login"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    local:MvxBind="Enabled(ButtonEnabled)"/>
```

But unable to get it to work. What I'm trying to achieve is that if EmailLogin variable is NullOrEmpty then button should be disabled. Where am i going wrong ?

Hopefully i'm not pushing this but can i add additional binding to it so that if it is disabled or enabled i can change the color of the button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the binding syntax to this:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Login"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    local:MvxBind="Enabled ButtonEnabled"/>
```

I don't know if you are doing it because your code doesn't show everything, but you will also need to call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => ButtonEnabled);` inside the setter of your `EmailLogin` property.

Also if you want to change the color of your button, you can install the [official color plugin](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color). Usage would be something like this:

```
private MvxColor _myColor;
public MvxColor MyColor
{
    get
    {   return _myColor; }
    set
    {
        _myColor = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyColor);
    }
}
```

And then: `local:MvxBind="Enabled ButtonEnabled; TextColor MyColor"`

Comment: Thank you, it has worked :D. My RaisePropertyChange for EmailLogin was set to itself (EmailLogin). Thanks for the additional info with regards to color. How would you set the color ? Is it instantiating MyColor with integer RGB ?

Comment: Great! Yes, you can instantiate one using RGB or you can find some predefined colors like `MvxColors.Red`. Make sure you install the package on your Core and Platform projects by the way :)

Comment: Excellent, Thanks dude :) just noticed your xml binding, it states TextColor MyColor, if its backgroundColor rather than TextColor would it be simply as local:MvxBind="Enabled ButtonEnabled; BackgroundColor MyColor"

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but do I need to call the MvxColor variable in RaisePropertyChanged on EmailLogin in order to pick up Enabled button color change ?

Comment: No problem! Yes, you can add a RaisePropertyChanged for your color in the setter (don't remove the raise for ButtonEnabled, add a new raise after it)

Comment: Acutally not to worry, got it to work. created custom class that inherits MvxColorValueConverter which then i used to pass in the xml like this. local:MvxBind="Enabled ButtonEnabled; BackgroundColor ButtonColour(ButtonEnabled)"